# Trying to individually control the servos in my robot using keyboard input

Tags: robotics

```
#include<Servo.h> 
Servo ser1;
Servo ser2;
Servo ser3;
Servo ser4;
Servo ser5;
int poser = 0; 
int val; 
int mot;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  ser1.attach(4);
  ser2.attach(5);
  ser3.attach(6);
  ser4.attach(7);
  ser5.attach(8);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.print("Choose the motor");
      mot=Serial.read();
      switch(mot)
      {
        case 1:
        {
            val = Serial.read();
            if (val == 'd') 
             {
                poser += 1;
                ser1.write(poser);
               delay(15);
             }
           if (val == 'a') 
             {
                poser -= 1; 
                ser1.write(poser);
                delay(15);
             }
           break;
         }
       case 2:
         {
           val = Serial.read();
           if (val == 'd') 
            {
               poser += 1;
               ser2.write(poser);
               delay(15);
            }
           if (val == 'a') 
            {
               poser -= 1; 
               ser2.write(poser);
               delay(15);
            }
           break;
         }
      case 3:
         {
           val = Serial.read();
           if (val == 'd') 
            {
              poser += 1;
              ser3.write(poser);
              delay(15);
            }
          if (val == 'a') 
            {
              poser -= 1; 
              ser3.write(poser);
              delay(15);
            }
          break;
         }
       case 4:
         {
            val = Serial.read();
            if (val == 'd') 
             {
                poser += 1;
                ser4.write(poser);
                delay(15);
             }
           if (val == 'a') 
             {
                poser -= 1; 
                ser4.write(poser);
                delay(15);
             }
           break;
         }
       case 5:
         {
           val = Serial.read();
           if (val == 'd') 
             {
                poser += 1;
                ser4.write(poser);
                delay(15);
             }
           if (val == 'a') 
             {
                poser -= 1; 
                ser4.write(poser);
                delay(15);
             }
           break;
          }
      default:
          {
              Serial.print("Type valid number");
              break;
          }
    }
  }
```

The code just shows "Choose the motor type valid number" repeatedly and the arm contorts as soon as I upload it. Can someone please check the code and tell me what could've gone wrong?

Comment: I had edited your code, basically add indentation so now your code is much clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values that you get from read are characters not integers. You will receive the character '1' or '2' not the integers you are currently checking for. As a result, none of the cases will match and you will always end up at the `default:` block of code.

So, you need to modify your case statement to check for characters. I.e.

```
switch(mot){
        case '1':       // put your digit in quoted
        {
```

And so on throughout the program

Comment: Oh, since you are controlling more than one servo, you might want to consider using more than one variable to track their current positions. Unless of course you want the movement of the most recently selected motor to move to one position offset from the previously selected motor. If you unsure what I mean, think about the value of poser if I select motor 1; 20 times and advance it. Poser will = 20. Then select motor 2 and advance it 1 time what will the value of poser be???

Comment: Yes, i think i understand what you mean. The value of poser will be 21. So to clarify, you're suggesting that i use different variables (eg.: poser1, poser2, poser3 etc.) for different motors right?

Comment: Actually I would suggest use an array but for now maintaining variables named like that is a good first step. If this has helped you can you please accept it as the answer (click the grey checkmark next to the answer that has helped you the most)

Comment: @aditii, did either of these answers help you? If so, please accept the one that helped you the most as the answer by clicking on the little check mark next to that answer. Accepting an answer is a way of saying "Thanks for the help".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add these line in your code.

`while(!Serial.available()){;}` before `mot = Serial.read();`

This will hold you logic till any input received from Serial.

Same you add before `val = Serial.read();`.